# HTML5 + EME + VIDEO

Tags: javascript, html5

Нужно проигрывать видео зашифрованное симметричным ключом. При этом скопировать видео нельзя и ключ тоже. Смотрю http://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/#decryption-key . Получилось сделать пример исползуя: org.w3.clearkey. Но в примере ключ открытый. Как сделать чтобы ключ от видео передавлся шифрованно в EME?